# Explaining a Statement in More Shorter Way

Tags: sentence-construction

I have some points in three-dimensional space, and these points are projected to x-y surface. I have an image which demonstrates projected points on x-y coordinate system. How can I explain this in one sentence?

> 1. This image shows abstract points in two-dimensional space to which real data samples correspond to
> 2. This image shows projected versions of data samples in three-dimensional space

These are my sentences, but I think both of them are weak. How can I express this?

Comment: This image shows 3D data projected onto a 2D surface.

Comment: Yes, this is called a "projection" and it is a [well-known mathematical concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra))